# Applying Transparent theme to Activity : Doesn't fit full screen in Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am working in an android application and I have **made an activity transparent by applying style** in the manifest file.But after applying this *my layout screen appears to be cut in the left and right* and seems to show only in the center.

In the emulator its appears to be fine but in ma android device(ICS) it show only in the middle. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**My Theme style is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Manifest file :**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SharescreenActivity"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
 </activity>
```

Comment: can you post screenshot of both emulator as well device

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this theme:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SharescreenActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: This works fine in ICS, but in 2.3 it does not work...It does not show the transparent activity .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="main"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style, checked on 2.3.3+ devices, works perfect

```
  <style name="Theme.XXXXXXX.Transparent" parent="Theme.XXXXXXX">
          <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
          <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
          <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
  </style>
```